# How can I search jqgrid column by its property?

Tags: javascript, search, jqgrid

My row looks like this:

```
{
    ...
    language: {
        id: 1,
        name: "English"
    }
}
```

jqGrid colModel contains the following:

```
{
    name: "language",
    index: "language",
    width: 100,
    stype: "select",
    searchoptions: {
        value: ":All;English:English;Norwegian:Norwegian"
    },
    formatter: function (value, options, row) {
        return value.name;
    },
}
```

I want to make a toolbar filter.

jqGrid prints out rows fine, but I cannot search based on this column. It never matches any language. I suspect that internally jqGrid filters based on original value and not on formatted one. Which ends up being something like comparing "English" with "[object Object]" :)

For some reason searchrules { custom: true, custom_func: somefunction } never gets triggered.

Is there a way to specify a property of a cell object to check against or have my own custom filtering function?